# How to enable drag and drop between normal & UAC elevated privileges applications

Tags: delphi, windows-7, drag-and-drop, delphi-2010, uac

I've read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4859680/1165880) about how one cannot use drag & drop files from explorer (typically running without extra admin privileges) with UAC-elevated applications.

One would think that elevating privileges to an EXE would give, well, **more** privileges, yet MS managed to give *less* privileges and break drag & drop functionality at the same time!

Anyway, while appreciated, the answer given by Mr. Arnaud Bouchez (disabling UIPI - User Interface Privilege Isolation) seems a bit *hackish*, **my question is: is there a recommended way to programmatically enable drag & drop without messing with user's registry**

I'm thinking about requesting "drag & drop ability" in manifest or something like that.

**NOTE: I mainly have this problem with Windows 7, but I assume the question is pertinent all Windows versions starting from Vista**

Comment: In fact MS got this right. You don't want some low life program sending messages to elevated process. You should re-consider why you want your GUI app to run elevated in the first place. And if it's essential, consider staying within the security design and not accepting things from lower rights apps.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: one such example is Total Commander that I use heavily: I always elevate it to be able to read/write program files and system32 folder but I still want to be able to drag from/to explorer.

Comment: @Remko You'd be better off just disabling UAC if you spend all of your time writing to those folders

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: MS basically disallowed elevated programs from interacting via drag n' drop with Windows Explorer (which is *not* a low life program!). With all due respect, I can't believe someone is not seeing the inability to use drag from Explorer as a handicap!  (BTW, yes, I *do* have **very** strong reasons to run my app in an elevated mode :()

Comment: Why do you run elevated? Anyway, if you want to sidestep this then just switch UAC off. If you let low priv processes invoke commands in high priv processes then it's easier for a low priv process to gain admin rights. That's a shatter attack.

Comment: It's beyond the scope of my question, let's just say I have to. Also, turning UAC off isn't an option. Even if I could, my application will **never** turn off users' UAC, that's crazy!

Comment: I didn't suggest that. Yes that would be crazy. I meant on your machine. One common route is only to elevate for the portions of your app that need elevated rights. So the main app runs as standard user. But the parts that need elevation run in a separate process. Or does everything your app do need elevation?

Comment: In any case, Sertac showed you how to do what you want

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: elevating proportions of my app isn't something that I considered, I'm not even sure how to do that and/or if it would be worth the effort. I'll consider that, thank you very much for the suggestion :)

Comment: You do need a separate process. Can be the same exe with special startup args.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can change the UIPI filter on the window of the privileged application by using [`ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to let file drag&drop related messages be received. `WM_DROPFILES` is the most obvious one, `WM_COPYDATA` is another one. There's also an undocumented message involved: `$0049`, you'll find sometimes it is referred to as `WM_COPYGLOBALDATA`. In fact a search on the last one, I believe, will reveal some code examples related with your question.